# getting erroe as Profile has S3/Kinesis inputs or outputs without configuring a "run-as" IAM role. what it means?

Tags: amazon-web-services

[ No credentials found for retrieving AWS resources. Typical causes:

1. Profile has S3/Kinesis inputs or outputs without configuring a "run-as" IAM role.
2. Profile uses CradleAWSCredentialsProvider without configuring a "run-as" IAM role.
3. Profile has "run-as" IAM role which cannot be assumed by the Cradle account's IAM role.

I have added IAM role,